# Binding in JSF not working

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I am trying to make a h:panelgrid visible and invisible by clicking on a button that's why i made this code:

```
<p:menu styleClass="ui-menubar" style="width:auto">
    <p:menuitem value="khraaaaaaaaa" actionListener="#{accounts.buttonUser()}"></p:menuitem>
  </p:menu>

    <h:panelGrid id="naalobouk" binding="#{accounts.pg1}">
            <h1>Activer/désactiver un compte étudiant</h1>
            <hr/>
            <h:form id="etudiants">
                <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Pas d'étudiant!"
                             paginator="true"
                             paginatorPosition="bottom"
                             rows="4"
                             value="#{accounts.etudiants}"
                             var="stu">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Les comptes étudiant" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="#">
                    <h:outputText value="#{stu.id}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="nom">
                    <h:outputText value="#{stu.nom}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="prenom">
                    <h:outputText value="#{stu.prenom}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="email">
                    <h:outputText value="#{stu.email}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="password">
                    <h:outputText value="#{stu.password}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="action">
                    <p:commandButton rendered="#{accounts.butshow}" value="#{stu.actif?'desactiver':'activer'}" action="#{accounts.doToggleStudentState(stu)}" update=":etudiants"/>
                </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

and here is my bean code

```
    private HtmlPanelGrid pg1 = new HtmlPanelGrid();//getter and setter

   public void buttonUser(){

        if(pg1.isRendered()==true){
            pg1.setRendered(false);;
        }
        if(pg1.isRendered()==false){
            pg1.setRendered(true);
        }
        }
```

When i click on the button nothing happens. What's the problem here ?

Comment: Can you show your whole bean code

Comment: The method shown is not called from the xhtml, and pg2 does not exist in xhtml, so at least for me it is confusing

Comment: The buttonaddUser function sets something to `false` and then immediately sets it back to `true`.

Comment: create a [mcve] please...

Comment: i made a mistake by posting the wrong code in my question and i have replaced the correct one !! Can anyoune see the problem now ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the method to negate the rendered property. In that case the method is flawed, as mentioned in the comments. The simplest code would be

```
public void buttonUser() {
    pg1.setRendered(!pg1.isRendered());
}
```

The main problem is that the p:menuItem by default uses ajax, which by default does'nt update anything on the page. So either update something, or don't use ajax;

```
<p:menuitem value="khraaaaaaaaa" actionListener="#{accounts.buttonUser()}" ajax="false">
```

With ajax you need to wrap the panelGrid in a component that will always be rendered, since you can't update a component that has not been rendered in the first place. Wrap the panelGrid in a panelGroup:

```
<h:panelGroup id="container">
```

and update that:

```
<p:menuitem value="khraaaaaaaaa" actionListener="#{accounts.buttonUser()}" update=":container">
```